# Search box in treeview with keyword search in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview which is populated using database connection. I want to add a search box to the treeview with keyword search and which returns parent nodes of trreview which have the keywords which are entered in the search box.

Do i have to make a new treeview and apply search on this and display this treeviw if keyword in search box matches or i can search in my original treeview and show only the matched nodes and make visibility false for others.

I have so far written this much code only

```
       string searchtxt = Txt_Search.Text.Trim();

        foreach (TreeNode Node in FolderStructure.Nodes)
        {
            if (Node.Text.StartsWith(Txt_Search.Text.Trim()))
            {
                Node.Select();
                Txt_Search.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Every suggestion will be welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: You should use the existing tree view and hide the nodes that do not match the search text

Comment: How can i do that because i think nodes do not have visible property.

Comment: You could filter the collection that is being assign as the data source to your treeview

Comment: yeah i can do that but i am trying to find a solution other than that because i don't want to hit database every time i search in my treeview. Other than that thanks for your solution.

Comment: can i cretae my treeview using list as a datasource....?????